# API Documentation on nginx - version error

Tags: nginx, swagger, openapi, fastapi

I have a fast api which runs well on localhost:8020 and I am able to see its documentation through localhost:8020/docs.

I also have an nginx container to redirect all the information on port 8020 to port 80 which its nginx.conf looks like this:

```
upstream api {
  server api:8020;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/ai-ocr;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/extra-conf.d/*.conf;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;

    # backend urls

    location /docs {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://api/docs;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
    # static files
    location /static/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }

    }
```

The issue is that when I want to have localhost:8020/docs on localhost:80/docs, I see this output in browser:

> Unable to render this definition The provided definition does not
> specify a valid version field.
>
> Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported
> version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n
> (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).

I tried having my fastapi to have these arguments to provide version but it doesn't work and I get the same error!

```
app = FastAPI(title="API_NAME",
              description="API_DESC",
              version="3.0.0",
              docs_url='/docs',
)
```

Comment: Routing issues This post will help [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67435296/how-to-access-fastapi-swaggerui-docs-behind-an-nginx-proxy)