# FastAPI Docs 403'ing when running on AWS APIGW/Lambda with Mangum

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fastapi

Trying to follow https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/?h=proxy#proxy-with-a-stripped-path-prefix but keep getting 403 when I trying to access `/docs` or `/redoc`:

I get the 403 error(image attached) if I do the below:

```
app = FastAPI(
        servers=servers,
        root_path="/latest", # Same 403 error without the root_path or omitting it
        root_path_in_servers=True, # Same issue when setting to False or omitting it
```

- `/docs` and `/redoc` works locally, just not once I push it to AWS APIGW/Lambda
- All other paths work without issue both locally and in APIGW/Lambda
- I am using [Mangum](https://mangum.io) when it's deployed to Lambda, locally I use uvicorn
- I tried variations of no `root_path` and `root_path_in_servers`=`True` or `False` and had the same issue
- I have an APIGW `GET /docs` path setup to route to the Lambda
- I have [API GW DNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-edge-optimized-custom-domain-name.html) set up so my DNS goes from `api.example.com` > API GW CloudFront URL which is mapped to my [APIGW stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-edge-optimized-custom-domain-name.html#how-to-custom-domains-mapping-console) named `/latest`, then it sends to Lambda

I also reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67435296/how-to-access-fastapi-swaggerui-docs-behind-an-nginx-proxy) with a similar/same issue, and tried:

```
docs_url='/latest/docs',
redoc_url='/latest/redoc',
openapi_url='/latest/openapi.json'
```

but encountered the same 403 error(image attached) or `{"detail":"Not Found"}`[image: 403 Error when loading /docs]

Comment: This seems to be a somewhat common problem. You could try looking through the suggestions in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/829) and see if any of them work for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
app = FastAPI(openapi_prefix='/dev/')
```

This worked for me. Here, dev is the API stage name